# Neo4j: Split string and get position

Tags: foreach, split, neo4j, cypher

I need to split a field in different values and store each value in a different node. For each created node I want to store the position.
Example:

```
Sentence             Words
My car is red        My;car;is;red
```

Using:

```
FOREACH (w IN SPLIT(line.TWords, ";") |
 MERGE (wd:Word {word: w})
```

I can split the field and store the different words, but I'd like to store the position on the relationship.

```
My car is red  -[HAS_WORD {position:1}]-> My
My car is red  -[HAS_WORD {position:2}]-> car
My car is red  -[HAS_WORD {position:3}]-> is
My car is red  -[HAS_WORD {position:4}]-> red
```

How can I get this?

**SOLUTION**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS  FROM 'file:///output_2016-05-06_0203_Neo4jImport.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR "\t"

MERGE (s:Segment{text: line.Source})
MERGE (ta:Segment{text: line.Target})

WITH SPLIT(line.SWords, ";") AS SWords, line, s, ta
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(SWords)-1) as i
    MERGE (s)-[r:HAS_WORD {position:i+1}]->(w:Word {word: SWords[i]})

WITH SPLIT(line.TWords, ";") AS TWords, line, ta
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(TWords)-1) as i
    MERGE (ta)-[r:HAS_WORD {position:i+1}]->(w:Word {word: TWords[i]})
```

Be sure that the fist `WITH` has the variable references necessary in second WITH: `WITH SPLIT(line.SWords, ";") AS SWords, line, s, ta`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a range based on the size of the split, assuming the node containing the sentence is identified with `sentence` :

```
WITH split(line.TWords, ';') as splitted
UNWIND range(0, size(splitted) -1) as i
MERGE (w:Word {word: splitted[i]})
MERGE (sentence)-[:HAS_WORD {position: i}]->(w)
```

*Update*

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///output_2016-05-06_0203_Neo4jImport.csv' 
AS line FIELDTERMINATOR "\t" 
MERGE (s:Segment{text: line.Source}) 
WITH SPLIT(line.SWords, ";") AS SWords, line 
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(SWords)-1) as i 
MERGE (s)-[r:HAS_WORD {position:i+1}]->(w:Word {word: SWords[i]})
```

Comment: Thanks. The SIZE function is what I was missing here
Anyway, I have tried this and I get the following error:
Variable `line` not defined (line 23, column 12 (offset: 651))
"WITH SPLIT(line.TWords, ";") AS TWords"

"line" is imported from a CSV and it's correctly accepted in other parts to import data

Comment: can you paste the complete modified query

Comment: USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS  FROM 'file:///output_2016-05-06_0203_Neo4jImport.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR "\t"

    MERGE (s:Segment{text: line.Source})

    WITH SPLIT(line.SWords, ";") AS SWords
    UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(SWords)-1) as i
        MERGE (s)-[r:HAS_WORD {position:i+1}]->(w:Word {word: SWords[i]})

Comment: ok, it is because line is not piped with the first WITH, I'll edit

Comment: what is line 23 in your query ?

Comment: The "original" query had more lines than the one I pasted, but these were working and shouldn't affect to the that part, so I removed them to simplify the question.

I see the problem:
I have two instances of that code part. The first one is correctly executed, but I get that error for the second one.
It seems I cannot use two "WITH" in the same query

Comment: you can use two WITH without any problem, we could help better with a complete status of the query though

Comment: Thank you very much @Christophe! 
I finally realize what the problem was. Each "WITH" must have a reference to the variables used in other "WITH" after it. I was mising "line" in the first with, so second one couldn't find it. I'll put the solution in the initial comment

Answer (score 2):

Use range:

```
MERGE (S:Sentence {text:"My car is red"})
  WITH S, SPLIT(S.text, " ") as words
  UNWIND RANGE(0,SIZE(words)-1) as i
    MERGE (S)-[r:HAS_WORD {position:i+1}]->(w:Word {word: words[i]})
RETURN S, r, w
```

Comment: Thanks @stdob 
I need to use a field containing the split words, as the sentences will be more complex  than "My car is red", containing punctuation and other characters that need to be taken into account. But your input has been quite useful too