# Using the data returned to manipulate string instead of returning it in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The data is in the following format

```
{"domain":"sdcastroverde.com","cat_labels_in":"Top/World/Galego/regional/Galicia/Lugo/municipalities/Castroverde"}
```

When I run a Cypher query

```
MATCH (n:Dmoz)
return split(n.cat_labels_in,'/') as data limit 10
```

I get the answer

```
["Top","World","Galego","regional","Galicia","Lugo","municipalities","Castroverde"]
```

I do not want to return the data, I want to use UNWIND on it so that I can write the "Tags" to the db as (:Tags{name:"Tag"}) and add relationship in the following fashion

```
(:Domain{name:"somedomain.com"})-[LINKS_TO]->((:Tags{name:"Tag"})) #first tag
(:Tags{name:"Tag"})-[LINKS_TO]->((:Tags{name:"Tag"})) #first tag to second tag and so on
(:Tags{name:"Tag"})-[LINKS_TO]->((:Domain{name:"anotherdomain.com"}))
```

Something like this [Neo4j: Split string and get position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109997/neo4j-split-string-and-get-position) but not from a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
// start with the sample data
WITH {domain:"sdcastroverde.com",cat_labels_in:"Top/World/Galego/regional/Galicia/Lugo/municipalities/Castroverde"} as node

// split the labels into tags
WITH node, split(node.cat_labels_in,'/') as tags 

// unwind the tags and make the chain of tags
UNWIND range(0, size(tags)-2) as i
  MERGE (a:Tags {name: tags[i] })
  MERGE (b:Tags {name: tags[i+1] })
  MERGE (a)-[:LINKS_TO]->(b)

// prepend the tag chain with the starting domain 
WITH node, tags
MATCH (a:Tags {name: tags[0]})
MERGE (:Domain{name:"somedomain.com"})-[:LINKS_TO]->(a)

// append the tag chain with the next domain
WITH node, tags
MATCH (a:Tags {name: tags[size(tags)-1]} )
MERGE (a)-[:LINKS_TO]->(:Domain {name:"anotherdomain.com"} )
```

Second solution per follow up question. The key here with mixed delimiters is to make a single collection out of the string with mixed delimiters first and then simply carry on as before.

```
//Start with some test data
WITH {domain:"sdcastroverde.com",cat_labels_in:"Top/World/Galego|Test/regional/Galicia|Test/Lugo/municipalities/Castroverde"} as node

// split up the list on forward slash
UNWIND split(node.cat_labels_in,'/') as tags

    // for each item in the first collection attempt to split on |
    UNWIND split(tags,'|') as tag

// recombine the split nodes into a single collection
WITH node, collect(tag) as tags

// then carry on as before in the above solution
UNWIND range(0, size(tags)-2) as i
    MERGE (a:Tags {name: tags[i] })
    MERGE (b:Tags {name: tags[i+1] })
    MERGE (a)-[:LINKS_TO]->(b)
WITH node, tags
MATCH (a:Tags {name: tags[0]})
MERGE (:Domain{name:"somedomain.com"})-[:LINKS_TO]->(a)
WITH node, tags
MATCH (a:Tags {name: tags[size(tags)-1]} )
MERGE (a)-[:LINKS_TO]->(:Domain {name:"anotherdomain.com"} )
```

Comment: Sorted!! Thanks Dave. There is one addition I want to make to this, the initial data is fetched using MATCH, so this is how i start the CYPHER query now. MATCH (n:Dmoz) WITH n, split(n.cat_labels_in,'/') as tags return tags LIMIT 10

Comment: The query works like a charm, however i have another issue with it. Some of the data has multiple tag chains separated with a Vertical bar (|), example {domain:"sdcastroverde.com",cat_labels_in:"Top/World/Galego|Top/World/Somethingelse|"}  how can I possibly UNWIND twice and how will i check if the row has more than one label?

Comment: @chandan - added a second solution that builds a single collection first out of the mixed delimiter string

Comment: Thanks for answering, there is however a problem with the second solution
What I am actually looking for is seperate tag paths


Top/World/Galego|Test/regional/Galicia|Test/Lugo/municipalities/Castroverde

should become

somedomain.com->Top->World->Galego->anotherdomain.com
somedomain.com->Test->regional->Galicia->anotherdomain.com
somedomain.com->Test->Lugo->municipalities->Castroverde->anotherdomain.com

in the solution the path gets saved as

Somedomain->Top->World->Galego->Test
Test->Regional->Galcia->Test
Test->Lugo->municipalities->Castoverde->anotherdomain.com

Comment: I understand what you want now. I can probably craft something a little later this morning.